# Why do you need to reassign variable after every change to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas Dataframes are suposed to be mutable, like lists. Therefore a change in the dataframe should be reflected in the previous reference.

However:

```
df.drop(to_delete)
```

Does not delete the indexes in the variable to delete.

```
df=df.drop(to_delete)
```

You have to reassign the variable. Why is that? Is the new the df than the same instance of the object?

Comment: Because those methods *create new dataframe objects* and on't modify the original objects in-place, note, most of these methods have an argument, `inplace=True` that will result in mutating the original object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the `inplace`

```
df.drop(to_delete, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. So without inplace it creates a copy? Can you set inplace as the default?

Comment: @BorutFlis some of the function have the inplace, without inplace = Truen, it will only create the view table